Swift: dropdown only working in Xcode preview, not actual app
When I test my Mac OS app within Xcode's preview, the dropdown selection of quote categories and "Get Quote" buttons both work as expected:

However, when I distributed this app to TestFlight (which I got Apple approval for), it doesn't work–that is to say, the dropdown options don't appear. Weirdly enough, the "Get Quote" button does work.

I suspect the "Get Quote" button works because of the additional .task{} and async method, but would really appreciate feedback on where this issue could be arising from.
import SwiftUI

struct QuoteView: View {
    @State private var quoteString = "No Quote Found"
    @State private var author: String? = nil
    @State private var fetching = false
    @AppStorage("quoteClassification") var quoteClassification: QuoteClassification = .everything
    
    @Environment(\.colorScheme) private var colorScheme
    let quotes: [QuoteJSON] // Add quotes as a parameter
    
    init(quotes: [QuoteJSON]) { // Initialize QuoteView with quotes
        self.quotes = quotes
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack(alignment: .center) {
                Picker("", selection: $quoteClassification) {
                    ForEach(QuoteClassification.allCases, id: \.self) { item in
                        Text(item.rawValue).tag(item)
                    }
                }
                .pickerStyle(MenuPickerStyle())
                Button("Get Quote") {
                    Task {
                        await getQuote(quoteClassification.classification)
                    }
                }
            }
            Spacer()

            if fetching {
                ProgressView()
            } else {
                VStack {
                    Text(quoteString)
                        .font(.system(size: 20))
                        .lineLimit(nil)
                        .minimumScaleFactor(0.5)
                        .foregroundColor(textColor) // Use the dynamic text color
                    Spacer()
                        .frame(height: 5) // Adjust the height as needed
                    Text(author ?? "") // Don't show author if blank
                        .font(.system(size: 14))
                        .foregroundColor(textColor) // Use the dynamic text color
                }
                .id(UUID())
            }
            Spacer()
        }
        .padding()
        .task {
            await getQuote(quoteClassification.classification)
        }
        .background(backgroundColor) // Set the background color based on colorScheme
        .environment(\.colorScheme, .dark) // Set the default color scheme to dark mode for testing
    }
    
    // Compute the dynamic text color based on the color scheme
    private var textColor: Color {
        if colorScheme == .dark {
            // Use white text for dark mode
            return .white
        } else {
            // Use black text for light mode
            return .black
        }
    }
    
    // Compute the dynamic background color based on the color scheme
    private var backgroundColor: Color {
        if colorScheme == .dark {
            return Color(red: 0.15, green: 0.1, blue: 0.05) // Dark wood color
        } else {
            return Color(red: 0.6, green: 0.4, blue: 0.2) // Light wood color
        }
    }
    
    func getQuote(_ classification: String) async {
        if classification.lowercased() == "all" {
            guard let randomQuote = quotes.randomElement() else {
                quoteString = "No Quote Found"
                author = nil
                return
            }
            // Assign the quote and author
            quoteString = randomQuote.text
            author = randomQuote.author == "Unknown Author" ? nil : randomQuote.author
        } else {
            // Fetch a random quote with the specified classification
            let filteredQuotes = quotes.filter { $0.classification.lowercased() == classification.lowercased() }
            guard let randomQuote = filteredQuotes.randomElement() else {
                quoteString = "No Quote Found"
                author = nil
                return
            }

            // Assign the quote and author
            quoteString = randomQuote.text
            author = randomQuote.author == "Unknown Author" ? nil : randomQuote.author
        }
    }

}


Why are you comparing TestFlight with Xcode previews? What if you run it locally yourself? What if you make a local release build yourself and run it?

Also getQuote isn't doing any async operations, so why are you marking it async? Furthermore, you're updating the @State properties from a non-main thread, which might be your actual issue here. Try mark getQuote with @MainActor

@ClausJørgensen Previously, I was making API calls with getQuote, so that's why it was initially asynchronous. To clarify, both when running locally and when launching the TestFlight version, the same issue with the dropdown not showing up arises.

@ClausJørgensen Marking the method as a @MainActor didn't seem to fix my dropdown issue: @MainActor func getQuote.

@ClausJørgensen Also, running it locally behaves the same as within TestFlight
